# Convergence verification cycle GS

Tags: openmdao

I am not sure to understand the access to the GS convergence information when running a problem which contains a Group class with a cycle.
To illustrate this, consider these two versions of the Sellar problem:

```
prob = Problem()
model = prob.model
model.add_subsystem('px', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['x'])
model.add_subsystem('pz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0])), promotes=['z'])
model.add_subsystem('d1', SellarDis1.SellarDis1(), promotes=['x', 'z', 'y1', 'y2'])
model.add_subsystem('d2', SellarDis2.SellarDis2(), promotes=['z', 'y1', 'y2'])
nlgbs = model.nonlinear_solver = NonlinearBlockGS()
nlgbs.options['maxiter'] = 8

prob.setup()
A = prob.run_model()
```

In this version, in the variable A there are convergence results such as

```
(False, 1.3188028447075339e-10, 3.6299074030587596e-12)
```

However, when defining the Sellar problem in the following form:

```
class SellarMDA(Group):
    def setup(self):
        indeps = self.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        indeps.add_output('x', 1.0)
        indeps.add_output('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0]))

        cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle', Group(), promotes=['*'])
        d1 = cycle.add_subsystem('d1', SellarDis1.SellarDis1(), promotes_inputs=['x', 'z', 'y2'], promotes_outputs=['y1'])
        d2 = cycle.add_subsystem('d2', SellarDis2.SellarDis2(), promotes_inputs=['z', 'y1'], promotes_outputs=['y2'])
        nl = cycle.nonlinear_solver = NonlinearBlockGS()
        nl.options['maxiter'] = 8


prob = Problem()
prob.model = SellarMDA()
prob.setup()
prob['x'] = 2.
prob['z'] = [-1., -1.]
C = prob.run_model()
```

In the variable C there is no relevant information to GS convergence, there is only

```
(False, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Is it possible to get the GS convergence information in the 2nd version as in the 1st without using a recorder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see what the solvers are doing, I would definitely recommend turning on the residual printing. You can do that individually for each solver, but I find it easier to use the problem method to turn it all on:

```
prob.set_solver_print(level=2)
```

Comment: Thank you however, if possible I would prefer to use a 'flag' resulting from the cycle GS convergence rather than residual printing as I want to use it in a MDF formulation. I want all along the optimization process to check if MDA convergence is reached and add a constraint if it is not the case to avoid to end up with a solution non feasible with respect to the cycle